# Eclipse not refreshing files using native hooks or polling

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I'm using Eclipse Kepler on OS X 10.9.2, and editing non-Java (HTML/JS/CSS) files in Sublime Text. I've checked "Refresh using native hooks or polling" from Window > Preferences > General > Workspace , but nothing is actually refreshed until I switch focus to Eclipse. So I have to save in ST, switch to Eclipse, then switch to the browser to refresh. I'd like to be able to skip switching to Eclipse, and thought that was what this option was supposed to allow. It's not a matter of just refreshing too quickly when I don't go via Eclipse - it never rebuilds until I switch to Eclipse. Is there any way to get this to work, or a workaround?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse faster auto refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550715/eclipse-faster-auto-refresh)