# Eclipse faster auto refresh

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I use Eclipse to run my application only. I use an external editor (Atom) for my main development. I turned on "Refresh using native hooks or polling" to have Eclipse refresh regularly (more info [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-52.htm) on how to do that).

My problem is... on OSX (MacBook Pro), it's a 15 sec delay. On my old crappy PC, it's pretty much instant.

**My question, is there any way to speed up the polling time on OSX?**

Comment: Thanks for the link to
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-52.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am not on a Mac, so I can't test this for you.)

Zend have written a refresher for Eclipse that uses Java 7 new features.

https://github.com/zendtech/studio-workspace-refresher

There are others out there to (https://github.com/zch/AutoRefresher and https://github.com/psxpaul/EclipseJava7Refresher) but based on the age and source of the zend one it is where I would start.

Note that you have hit upon one of the biggest issues people have with Eclipse. The new (as of Oct 2015) Friends Of Eclipse funding is aiming to tackle some of these issues. This one has a bug you can track [Bug 480551](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=480551).

Comment: Glad I'm not alone in this frustration. Tried the plugins, seem to have the same delay but, now I know where to point my frustrations. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration that changes the operation of the polling refresh used on the Mac (`org.eclipse.core.internal.refresh.PollingMonitor`).

The refresh runs much quicker on Windows because it uses file system native hooks rather than polling.

Comment: No config in the ui or in setting file outside the ui? In other words, it can't happen?

Comment: No config anywhere, all timing is hard coded in the class.

Comment: How can I go about changing that hardcoded value? Sorry for my ignorance in this field, not a java dev.

Comment: There is no reasonable way to change this. You could try writing your own 'refresh provider' using the `org.eclipse.core.resources.refreshProviders` extension point but that is hard work.