# Avoid refreshing html pages in eclipse for spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I'm using Spring Boot to deploy a webbased app (services on the backend, SPA app for the front end).

I'm not using Eclipse to edit my html-related files.
If I put those files under "**resources**", when using Eclipse to debug the app, **any changes (to the html-related files) made using the other editor is not picked up by the "embedded" tomcat, unless I refresh the file in Eclipse too.**

Everything works great if I put the html-related files in webapp/: I don't have to refresh the files in Eclipse; but then the files are not picked up by the jar maven build (because spring boot jar is not supposed to pick them by design...)

How do you usually work with html-resources?
I don't want to use Eclipse to edit my html-related files, and I don't want to use nodejs/other proxy-style server tool (I have a capable webserver called "tomcat", I don't see the need to have yet another tool to install/configure/update etc)

Comment: What Eclipse version are you using? It doesn't happen to me with neon2/Maven project.

Comment: Actually, I'm using STS 3.8.2.RELEASE (not Eclipse). How is it not happening to you? If you put files under "resources" they are handled by Java, so a reload is needed... which is not the case with webapp.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550715/eclipse-faster-auto-refresh

Comment: Have you tried to enable 'Refresh using native hooks or polling'? Go to  Windows-->Preferences-->Workspace and enable 'Refresh using native hooks or polling'.

Comment: Yes! That's the one! Anyway it takes 2 secs to refresh it, unless it's already open... :( but it's better than nothing. Now another problem... it takes a while to "copy 3842 resources" whenever a build kicks in... still don't understand why spring boot don't pick static things from webapp when doing the jar... maybe I'll open another question on that.

Comment: added new question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197456/add-src-main-webapp-to-jar-for-spring-boot