# Add src/main/webapp to jar for spring boot

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

The spring boot docs says you should put the "static" html resources under /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources).
But this leads to 2 problems:

1. I'm using an external tool to edit those files, and Eclipse
   **refreshes after 2 seconds** (so when I'm editing an html file, I can't
   just refresh the page: I have to wait...)
2. whenever I change a
   java file, a **"Copying 3268 resources"** task starts: it takes time,
   and if I start the app in debug it actually crashes if the task is
   not finished.

So: how can I set my maven "package" phase to copy those files, while keeping everything the way it is for debugging ("compile" phase?)

Answer (score 0):

Using this plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html you can copy files during the specified phase on maven.

But I've never had the problem you mentioned, I'm using Intellij Idea, you should give it a try

Comment: I'm not that good with maven; but even if I specify "prepare-package" as phase, if I don't put any goal it won't do it; and if the goal is "copy-resources" it will happen at compile time. I need it at "prepare-package", but I don't know what to use as a goal then...

Comment: Why you don't put any goal? The goal is "what" you want to do, and the phase is "when" you want do it. Did you try specify "prepare-package" as phase and goal as  "copy-resources"?

Comment: Yes, with prepare-package as phase and copy-resources as goal it gets executed at compile time (which is not good). My understanding is that is the goal that drives, not the phase. At the moment I'm using an antrun plugin with goal "run" and phase "prepare-package" and it seems to be working